# Android Studio opens the collapsed functions when i reformate my code

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, format

Hello Im new to android studio (flutter) and when i reformate my code the android studio opens all the collapsed scoops is there any way to prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in exactly in the same situation. I don't have a concrete solution for your problem.

If you hit `CTRL ALT -` will collapse all functions
If you hit `CTRL ALT +` will expand all functions

This is a good shortcut that may do the work for you.